# how to view pdf as a dynamic website in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I'm working on a PHP project, that has all the content stored in PDF files with the very well arranged format, so I don't wanna convert or rewrite into HTML. Is there a way to view pdf directly from server one by one page without downloading the complete file?

Answer (score 0):

Download PDFObject library from https://pdfobject.com/ and check the below code: I hope it will work you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pdf Read</title>
    <style>
          .pdfobject-container { height: 500px;}
          .pdfobject { border: 1px solid #666; }
   </style>
   <script src="pdfobject.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="example1"></div>
        <script>PDFObject.embed("pdfread.pdf", "#example1");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not what I want, clientside js will download complete file from the server then render view, but in my case, I want to parse the pdf in server  so a user won't have to download complete pdf, we want to load one page at a time in the browser to load fast. The server has to send one page at a time and when a user clicks next send next page, not the complete file. Some of pdfs are larger than 30 megabytes so for this scenario, this is worst option for me,